# Extract multiple data from JSON API using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am able to extract the specific data from the url.

```
    weather_data = r.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location)
    json_weather = weather_data.text
    weather_info = json.loads(json_weather)

    print weather_info['coord']['lat']
    print weather_info['coord']['lon']
```

Here is what is Diplayed on the API

The question is, how can i extract multiple data and put in a 1 list (dict) rather than extract it one by one.

For example, i want to put 'lat', 'lon', 'humidity' in the same list.

```
{u'base': u'stations',
 u'clouds': {u'all': 40},
 u'cod': 200,
 u'coord': {u'lat': 51.51, u'lon': -0.13},
 u'dt': 1439476222,
 u'id': 2643743,
 u'main': {u'humidity': 88,
           u'pressure': 1012,
           u'temp': 291.71,
           u'temp_max': 293.15,
           u'temp_min': 290.15},
 u'name': u'London',
 u'rain': {u'1h': 1.78},
 u'sys': {u'country': u'GB',
          u'id': 5091,
          u'message': 0.0242,
          u'sunrise': 1439440988,
          u'sunset': 1439493986,
          u'type': 1},
 u'visibility': 9000,
 u'weather': [{u'description': u'light intensity shower rain',
               u'icon': u'09d',
               u'id': 520,
               u'main': u'Rain'}],
 u'wind': {u'deg': 60, u'speed': 4.6}}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  In this example, `weather_info` *is* a Python dictionary.

Comment: weather_info is a dictionary (or a list, but less likely).

Comment: JSON objects *are* converted to a dictionary by [default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

Comment: @larsks, i have now clarify my problem in more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is, how do you extract only the latitude, longitude and humidity values from that data set.

If that's the case, try this version. It takes each location in the list `locations` and then collects the coordinates and humidity index:

```
import requests

url = 'http://...' # url goes here
locations = ['London', 'New York', 'Chicago'] # adjust as required
results = {}

for loc in locations:
   response = requests.get(url, params={'q': loc})
   if response.status_code == 200:
       data = response.json()
       results[loc] = {'lat': data[u'coord'][u'lat'],
                       'lon': data[u'coord'][u'lon'],
                       'humidity': data[u'main'][u'humidity']}
   else:
       print('No results for {}'.format(loc))

print(results)
```

Make sure you have the latest version of requests (`pip install -U requests`).